# Core Dara in Swift bug on saving gata NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: swift, core-data

What is the reason of this crash. I think it is somewhere while saving data to core data with relationships

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<User 0x2817a0dc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity User is not key value coding-compliant for the key "(null)".'
```

I think keys names are ok, I am using generated classes.

Comment: If you have changed something in your core data model you might want to clean the project and rebuild.

Comment: Yes but this happen when I deleted app, and reinstall it again with clean database, if there was old data crash does not happen

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found reason of this error. It happens

1. If we insert some ManagedObjects to CoreData
2. While inserting update relationships
3. AND (Important!) some of this relationships are "No Inverse" in Core Data model.

Then in spite I am setting relationship from good side there relationship is correctly defined, when there is many relationships updates/ that have another relationship updates then crash happen.

I think avoiding No Inverse relationship could help solve this issue.